# Characterisation of almost sure convergence vs. convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

In a lecture on mathematical statistics we defined convergence in probability and convergence almost surely. The definitions are for general metric spaces so let me show them here with a general metric $d: S \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ defining the distance. I actually find it easier to read and understand that way. Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, X be random variables

1. Almost sure (a.s.) convergence:

$$P(\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} d(X_n, X) = 0) =1$$

2. Convergence in probability:

$$\forall \varepsilon >0 \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} P(d(X_n,X) > \varepsilon) = 0$$

We also had a criterion for a.s. convergence

> **Theorem**
>
> $ X_n \overset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} X$  a.s. $\iff$ $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb{Q}: \underset{m \to \infty}{\lim} P(\underset{n \geq m}{\sup} d(X_n,X) > \varepsilon) = 0$ (*)

My problem in understanding lies here: I know the theorem is used later to prove that from a.s. convergence we can deduce convergence in probability. But seeing the form of the right hand side of the theorem I don't understand why the reverse does not hold. I know there are counter examples where the reverse is not true but they don't help me here on an intuitive level.

Suppose convergence in probability holds. So the measure of the differences converges to $0$. Now I see why for a fixed $m$ we could get that

$P(\underset{n \geq m}{\sup} d(X_n,X) > \varepsilon) > 0$

but if $m$ goes to infinity should I not reach a point where not even the supremum of the differences leaves the $\varepsilon$-corridor? What am I understanding wrong?

Comment: Indeed, It is challenging at the beginning to understand the difference. One key difference is that $P(d(X_n,X)>\varepsilon )$ is a condition on the distance between the two variables $X$ and $X_n$. On the other side, $P(\sup_{n>m}d(X_n,X)<\varepsilon )$, is a condition that requires the whole sequence, after m, to be close to $X$. Requiring that $P(d(X_n,X)>\varepsilon )$ gets small (converging to 0) does not allow you to conclude that some points of the sequence occasionally escape the corridor - so the limit of $P(\sup_{n>m}d(X_n,X)>\varepsilon )$ does not need to go to 0. Hope that helps.